# How can I use Chrome Dev Tools to locate what is causing the blue bar at the bottom of the attached screenshot

Tags: polymer, google-chrome-devtools, polymer-2.x

[image: Screenshot]

This is a Polymer 2 application using the `<app-header-layout>`.  The blue band at the very bottom of the screenshot exactly corresponds to the area scrolled onto screen by scrolling the content below the header bar up.

I want to use Chrome Dev Tools to find out what is causing this particular color at this particular place, as it does not seem to correspond to an element; only to the scrolled in content.

Unfortunately, the color that it is, is one of my standard colors and is defined at the top of my application (that is using the "app shell" concept there is a single element that is the entire application and that defines a css3 variable `--app-primary-color` that is this color) so its difficult to spot.

In chrome dev tools I have tried both "inspecting" the element at that point on the screen, and selecting what should be the element containing the foreground content at that point in the screen, but there is no clue there about this color.

So how can I use chrome dev tools to give me some clue as to where this color comes from

EDIT:  I found the cause of the color band, namely that it was the specified background colour on the html element.  Why it caused the particular band on overflow content I still have no idea, nor have I discovered how to use Chrome dev tools to diagnose that

Comment: Obviously it's either a browser bug or incorrect CSS/whatnot in your code. Without access to the actual app I can't tell which.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am not asking you to solve the problem, rather tell me how to use Chrome Dev Tools to locate the source.  I can't give you the actual app because its enormous, and also private for a client of mine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Polymer but so far it really looks like a bug in Chrome/Polymer. In such cases the usual approach is to eliminate everything except the bare minimum needed to reproduce the issue and if it turns out to be an actual bug, submit this skeleton app on https://crbug.com or Polymer bugtracker/repo.